# How to convert string to symbol in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have json data in the following format.

```
 var jsonData={
"India":["Australia","New Zealand","Pakistan","England"],
"Pakistan":["New Zealand","India","England"],
"Bangladesh":["New Zealand","India","England","SouthAfrica","Australia"],
"Srilanka":["New Zealand","India","England","SouthAfrica","Australia"],
"Australia":["New Zealand","Pakistan","India"],
"New Zealand":["Pakistan","India","England","SouthAfrica","Australia"],
"SouthAfrica":["Srilanka","India","Pakistan"],
"England":["Srilanka","New Zealand","Pakistan","Bangladesh"]
 };
```

I will get country name from dropdown list.it is selected by user.

```
  var countryName=document.getElementById("pop1").value;
```

Now I want to fetch specific country data from json data based on `countryName` value.

for example.If `countryName` value is equals to `India` then it should returns `jsonData.India` data.

How to do this.

Thanks

Comment: There's obviously no way to stop people saying "json" over and over again...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass your variable like this:

```
jsonData[ countryName ]
```

So basically you can access object properties in JS by 2 ways:

```
sobeObj.value
```

or

```
someObj[ 'value' ]
```

Inside brackets can be string or variable that represent the string.

Answer (score 0):

Like that:

```
var countryName = 'India';
var countries = jsonData[countryName];
```